# Toggling visibility in Kotlin, isVisible unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

Slowly learning Kotlin.  Just generating a random number from a roll.  If roll = 9 I want to make the button and seekbar invisible.

I'm using the toggleVisibility function to accomplish this, but the Kotlin compiler sees isVisible as a unresolved reference

```
package com.example.randomizer

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.VideoView
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rollButton)
        val resultsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultsTextView)
        val seekBar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
        val winText = "9 You Win !"




        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            val rand = Random().nextInt(seekBar.progress)
            resultsTextView.text = rand.toString()
            if (rand == 9) {
                resultsTextView.text = winText
                seekBar.toggleVisibility()
                rollButton.toggleVisibility()
            }

        }



    }

    fun View.toggleVisibility() {
        if (this.isVisible()) {
            this.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler error:

```
unresolved reference isVisible
```

Comment: I don't think there's any `isVisible()` method, but you should rather check `if (visibility == View.VISIBLE)`. That's because there are 3 possible visibility values: `VISIBLE`, `INVISIBLE` and `GONE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you define `isVisible` for a View by yourself?
[View](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View.html) class has no method called`isVisible()`.

As @user2340612 said, it can be defined as:

```
fun View.isVisible(): Boolean {
    return this.visibility == View.VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  I was under the assumption that there would be a isVisible method in the View class.

Comment: It does exist as a Kotlin extension, you just don't have the right dependency as per [the actual correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56464337/1676363)

Answer (score 13):

As others mentioned above, you can either specify `isVisible()` as an extension function by yourself.

```
fun View.isVisible() = this.visibility == View.Visible
```

Or you can add the KTX view dependency and start using some of the methods there. I recommend you have a look at: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).isVisible:kotlin.Boolean

To import and start using KTX add to your Dependencies in `build.gradle`

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2"
```

KTX is a set of Kotlin extensions that are commonly used. Check also: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx

Answer (score 1):

There is no `isVisible()` method inside the class `View`.
You can define your extension method like this:

```
fun View.toggleVisibility() {
    this.visibility = if (this.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.INVISIBLE else View.VISIBLE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Vadim Kotov said, `isVisible` is not a method that exists within `View`.  There is, however, a `getVisibility()` function that will return one of the three possible visibility values: `VISIBLE`, `INVISIBLE`, or `GONE`.  You can use these results to determine the visibility and set it how you want.